# How to access service running on host machine from local pc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Ubuntu VM instance running on my Amazon-AWS. 
Inside that VM I have a service running on https://localhost:1337
I created Elastic IP to that VM.
Now I want to want to access that service from my local PC from a URL.
Is it possible to do so? If possible, how?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on SuperUser.com.

Comment: You would open port 1337 in the security group, and access it via the elastic IP, like: https://<elastic-ip>:1337

Comment: Thanks @MarkB that did help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to open the port 1337 in the security group, and access it via the elastic IP, like: https://:1337 as @Mark B has mentioned.